# Unable to start mariadb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, mariadb, troubleshooting

My ubuntu server's mariadb service was down and from running "journalctl -xe" I could see that the error must be caused by courrupted files so i append the following entry to my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file

innodb_force_recovery = 1

and restarted the mariadb server and it restarted somehow now I have commented out the  the above line from my my.cnf file and mariadb seems to running.

my question is that what happens when I put the above entry in my.cnf file.
Does it remove the corrupted files? need an explanation of what the above entry Is there any follow up needs to be done to fix the issue permanently?

It would be great if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

The innodb_force_recovery server system variable sets the recovery mode. A mode of 0 is normal use, while the higher the mode, the more stringent the restrictions. Higher modes incorporate all limitations of the lower modes.

Generally, it is best to start with a recovery mode of 1, and increase in single increments if needs be. **With a recovery mode < 4, only corrupted pages should be lost**. With 4, secondary indexes could be corrupted. With 5, results could be inconsistent and secondary indexes could be corrupted (even if they were not with 4). A value of 6 leaves pages in an obsolete state, which might cause more corruption.

Comment: Hi thanks for the update. However the curropted files are lost right ? Is there any thing to do after this I just commented out the line from my.cnf file

Comment: Yeah, that's it. After recovery you can put back to zero.